# Determine single unique substring per string in list of strings with shared prefix or suffix

Tags: java, string, algorithm

Suppose I have a list of strings with a shared prefix &/or suffix.

I want to determine the single unique substring per string.

IF the strings share neither prefix nor suffix, return an empty string.

examples:

```
1
Input:
      { "Katie walked to the beach in her fresh new kicks",
        "Katie walked to the arcade in her fresh new kicks",
        "Katie walked to the gazebo in her fresh new kicks"}
Output:
      { "beach",
        "arcade",
        "gazebo"}
--------------------------------------------------------
2
Input:
      { "Eric walked home with nothing",
        "Brad jogged home with nothing",
        "Brad jogged home with seven bucks"}
Output:
      {""}
--------------------------------------------------------
3
Input:
      { "Jill had fun",
        "Jill had salad for lunch",
        "Jill had twins!" }
Output:
      {"fun",
       "salad for lunch",
       "twins!"}
--------------------------------------------------------
4
Input:
      { "Bread",
        "Butter",
        "Bill Nye" }
Output:
      {"read",
       "utter",
       "ill Nye"}
```

interested in pseudocode, java code, or suggestions.

EDIT:  thank you, commenters & answerers, for helping me understand this problem better -- my question was nonsense, as worded earlier.  hopefully it is consistent now.  i think some of these answers are correct, i will examine w/in a couple days

Comment: Do all your strings start with "Katie walked to the "?

Comment: Is there always just a common prefix and a common suffix, or can there be common segments in the middle that also need to be removed?

Comment: What output are you expecting from, for example, `{ "katie 123 bobby", "katie 345 bobby", "johny 123 katie", "johny 123 jackie" }` ?

Comment: oh great questions.  sorry, my post was unclear, i will edit.  @FalconUA, that input should return an empty string

Comment: @j_random_hacker Yes - the common segments are limited to the prefix and suffix.  no common segments in the middle

Comment: OK, but then your example 2 is confusing, since stripping common prefixes and (in this case empty) suffixes gives {"walked home with nothing.", "jogged home with nothing", "jogged home with seven bucks."}.  Do you want to treat "no shared suffix" (and maybe "no shared prefix") as special cases that force the result to {"""}?

Comment: @j_random_hacker yes.  the strings must have a shared suffix or shared prefix.

Comment: Do the prefix, substring, and suffix consist of complete words only?  Your examples strongly imply this.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc no.  that's why i added #4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
static List<String> uniqueString(List<String> lines) {
    List<String> uniques = new ArrayList<>();
    if (lines.size() == 0) return uniques;
    String prefix = lines.get(0);
    String suffix = lines.get(0);
    for (String s : lines) {
        while (!s.startsWith(prefix))
            prefix = prefix.substring(0, prefix.length() - 1);
        while (!s.endsWith(suffix))
            suffix = suffix.substring(1);
    }
    if (prefix.length() == 0 && suffix.length() == 0)
        uniques.add("");
    else
        for (String s : lines)
            uniques.add(s.substring(prefix.length(), s.length() - suffix.length()));
    return uniques;
}

@Test
public void testUniqueSubstrig() {
    System.out.println(uniqueString(Arrays.asList(
        "Katie walked to the beach in her fresh new kicks",
        "Katie walked to the arcade in her fresh new kicks",
        "Katie walked to the gazebo in her fresh new kicks"
    ))); // -> [beach, arcade, gazebo]
    System.out.println(uniqueString(Arrays.asList(
        "Eric walked home with nothing",
        "Brad jogged home with nothing",
        "Brad jogged home with seven bucks"
    ))); // -> []
    System.out.println(uniqueString(Arrays.asList(
        "Jill had fun",
        "Jill had salad for lunch",
        "Jill had twins!" 
    ))); // -> [fun, salad for lunch, twins!]
    System.out.println(uniqueString(Arrays.asList(
        "Bread",
        "Butter",
        "Bill Nye"
    ))); // -> [read, utter, ill Nye]
}
```

Comment: Looks correct to me, but because you call `startsWith()` and `substring()` inside the inner loop this takes O(n^2) time (and also performs unnecessary heap allocations and deallocations) when an O(n) algorithm (see user1952500's answer) is possible.  This probably isn't a big deal for short strings, but the faster algorithm isn't really any more complicated.

Answer (score 2):

Ignoring example (2), which should give the output mentioned by @j_random_hacker, we could use the following simple method which has O(n) time complexity:

1. Start from index 0 and go to the right until there is a mismatch in characters. Let this be at 'l'.
2. Start from the end of the string and go to the left while counting characters until there is a mismatch in characters. Let this be at 'r'.

The substrings you need are between 'l' and 'r' (inclusive) from all of the strings.

For example:

Input:
      { "Jill had fun.",
        "Jill had salad.",
        "Jill had twins." }

Step1 gives: 8 for all three strings (this should always be a single index)

Step2 gives: 1. This maps to 11, 13, 13. (string-length - r)

Hence the substrings are 8-11, 8-13, 8-13 which are {"fun", "salad", "twins"}.

**EDIT:** This needs to be special-cased for the case there l==0 and r==0. In that case we need to return "" as per the new wording of the problem. Note that the special case is not ugly; it in fact captures the departure from semantics in the problem perfectly.

Comment: Looks good, but it would help to clarify that r counts characters *from the end of the string* -- so that just a single value of r (which is 1 in your example, not "11, 13, 13") is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all the strings start with the same text, "Katie walked to the ", use this snippet:

```
String place = "Katie walked to the YOUR_PLACE_HERE".split(" ")[4];
```

In a method:

```
public String[] getPlaces(String[] strings) {
    String[] places = new String[strings.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
        places[i] = strings[i].split(" ")[4];
    }
    return places;
}
```

A more versatile method would be:

```
public static String[] getPlaces(String[] strings, String splitString) {
    String[] places = new String[strings.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
        places[i] = strings[i].split(" ")[splitString.split(" ").length];
    }
    return places;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also try this simple way using regex!

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
 String[] str = new String[4];      
 str[0] = "Katie walked to the beach in her fresh new kicks";
 str[1] = "Katie walked to the arcade in her fresh new kicks";
 str[2] = "Katie walked to the gazebo in her fresh new kicks";
 str[3] = "Katie walked to the mall in her fresh new kicks";


 for (int i = 0; i<str.length; i++) {
 System.out.println(str[i].replaceAll("Katie|walked|to|the|in|her|fresh|new|kicks", ""));
 }

}
```